# Cannot upload a large file through HTML form in an appscript webapp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I cannot upload a file,which has a size of 177 MB into google drive through an HTML form using appscript.It doesn't show up any errors.But the browser uploading status is 0%.

I am using the following code for uploading in my appscript file.

Following is my Appscript code

```
function uploadFile(e) {
      var link=[],file_extension=[];
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Drawing Register");

      for(var j in e){
        if((j=="urlLink") && (e["urlLink"]!=="")){
         var fileId=getIdFromUrl(e["urlLink"]);
         var type=DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getMimeType();//to find whether if its a google document/spreadsheet
         var gtype=type.substring(type.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
         file_extension.push(gtype);
         link.push(e["urlLink"]);
         continue;
        }

       for(var s=0;s<e[j].length;s++){
         var fileImage =e[j][s];

         var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Document_Folder);

         var image=folder.createFile(fileImage);

         var fileName =image.getName();
         if(fileName=="Untitled"){
          DriveApp.getFileById(image.getId()).setTrashed(true);
         }
         else{
           var ext=fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1); // finding extension of file uploaded
           link.push(image.getUrl());
           file_extension.push(ext);
         }
        }
      }

      var response = {
      'link':link,
      'extension':file_extension,
    }
   return response;
```

Following is my javascript code

```
function addDrawing(val){
        t=1;
         changedFieldValues=[];
         var html="";
         if(val!=undefined){
           revisedDrawing=true;//true if selected row needs to be uploaded with revised drawings
           revisedDrawingRow=val;//row no
         }

         html+='<h3 class="modal-head-color text-center">Add Drawings Or Documents</h3><form onsubmit="loadingModal();google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessUploadDrawing).uploadFile(this);return false">';
//-------------------------drawing--------------------           

         for(var k=1;k<5;k++){

          html+='<div class="form-group">';
          if(k==1){
           html+='<label><strong>Upload pdf version of file</strong></label>';
           html+='<input type="file" class="form-control" accept="application/pdf"  name="myImage" required />';
           html+='</div>';
           continue;
          }
          if(k==2){
           html+='<label><strong>If it is a google document,paste the link below</strong></label>';
           html+='<input type="url" class="form-control" name="urlLink"/>';
           html+='</div>';
           continue;
          }


          html+='<label>Upload Original File '+t+'(if applicable)</label>';
          html+='<input type="file" class="form-control" id="file'+t+'" name="myImage" />';
          html+='</div>';
          t++;
         }

          html+='<div id="uploadFile">';//for adding upload file boxes dynamically

          html+='</div>';

          html+='<button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-info" onclick="appendUploadBox();">+</button>';
          html+='<br><input type="submit" class="btn btn-purple btn-block"/>';


        html+='</form>'; 
        modalTxt.innerHTML=html;
        modal.style.display = "block";
       }
```

If anyone has any ideas, please do share.

Comment: In your situation, unfortunately, the file more than 50 MB cannot be uploaded because the maximum blob size is 50 MB in Google Apps Script. In your case, it is required to use the resumable upload. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

Comment: I tried doing this through FileReader .But the browser crashed after  uploading the large file

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the whole script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.